# java generic bound type-why does extends only mean extending the classes and implementing the interface?

Tags: java

I am learning generic types in Java now. To restrict the type argument passed to the type parameter, we use the keyword "extends". It means to either "extends"(as in class) or "implements" (as in interfaces). I don't understand why it can't mean to "extends" the the interface?

Comment: ... maybe because you don't "extend" interfaces? As you stated, you "extend" classes and "implement" interfaces. Those are the correct terms.

Comment: It's just terminology that Java uses.  Java uses "extends" for classes and "implements" for interfaces.  You might want to check out some of the basic Java syntax on a tutorial site.

Comment: If I misunderstand your question, please correct me, but as far as I can tell, you answered it yourself.

Comment: @Jashaszun I guess he meant when interface `A` extends interface `B`; @Jie I think the terminology there just lets you request that your generic type must be a subtype of whatever class or interface you indicate, with this meaning there's no need to distinguish between class and interface.

Comment: Yes I know that classes can "extends" classes and implement the interfaces, and interfaces can only "extends" interfaces. If I write : public class A < T extends interface1>, the type argument I can pass to T can only be classes that implements interface1, but I am wondering why it can't be the interface that extends interface1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Interface only extends another interface ... class implements the interface
the only class that extends the interface will be the abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an interface when specifying (what's the right term?) a generic type (I had to answer to post the code):

```
class MyGeneric<T extends MyBaseInterface> {

}

interface MyBaseInterface {

}

interface MySubInterface extends MyBaseInterface {

}


public class GenericsTest {

    private MyGeneric<MySubInterface> x = new MyGeneric<>();

}
```

As I said in my comment above, in `<T extends X>` "extends" is just a way to require that T is a subtype of X (where X can be a class or an interface).

Comment: That answered my question. Thanks alot!